# ¿Cómo hago que mi aplicación no se abra por encima de otras?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Mi aplicación tiene una pantalla de carga que termina con un `startActivity()` al `MainActivity`.

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(startIntent);
```

De forma paralela, esa pantalla de carga tiene un botón que lleva a una página de Instagram. El problema es que, si el usuario visita la página con el botón, cuando la pantalla de carga termina, mi aplicación saca al usuario de Instagram bruscamente para llevarlo a `MainActivity`.

¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi aplicación termine sus procesos mientras el usuario visita la página de Instagram y **le deje hacer sus cosas sin interponerse**?

El proceso que manda al `MainActivity` está en un hilo, y el botón que lleva a Instagram se ejecuta en el hilo principal.

Answer (score 1):

Como el proceso para abrir `MainActivity` y tu página de Instagram es asíncrono, mas aún si este proceso se realiza dentro de un hilo, por lo tanto no puedes asegurar uno se abra después de otro siempre.

Aquí lo aconsejable es abrir el MainActivity:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
startActivity(startIntent);
```

y dentro de `MainActivity` abrir la página de Instagram, esto dentro de `onCreate()` :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   //* Abre página de Instagram
 ...
 ...

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por ahora me quedo con tu solución. De todas formas, tiene que haber alguna forma de hacerlo como dije... Ya que de esta manera, el usuario no es dirigido a Instagram hasta que se ejecuta MainActivity, y eso tarda unos segundos.

Comment: Como estabas abriendo Instagram , un Intent para abrir la url o dentro de un WebView en una Activity? @PabloAsenjoNavas-Parejo

Comment: En un intent, así: (Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setData(Uri.parse("http://..."), y paralelamente ocurre esto otro: startActivity(new Intent(StartActivity.this, MainActivity.class)) que saca al usuario de Instagram bruscamente. He resumido los códigos.